# tvOS 11 update UICollectionView Crash

Tags: swift, swift3, tvos, apple-tv, tvos10

Any ideas on what could be causing app to crash on back After automatic update to tvOS 11? same version of app on tvos 10 doesnt crash.

*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3698.33.3.301/UICollectionView.m:1964

2017-12-14 15:23:16.113879+0100 UR Play[370:24888] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '**UICollectionView dataSource is not set'.**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that either in your code you implemented dataSource and linked it to your UICollectionView or you can do that using the Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The crash was solved by reseting the UICollectionview datasource to nil in deinit
This post helped understand what's going on
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1154